# How do I sort a sorted linked list's sorted area?

Tags: c++, sorting, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list with each node containing a word, letter count of the word, and how many times that word has been used:

```cpp
class Node{
    public:
        string word;
        Node* next;
        short int letterCount;
        short int timesUsed=1;
};

class LinkedList{
    public:
        Node* head;
        LinkedList();
        void insert(string word);
        void sort();
        string search(int lettersUsed, int timesUsed);
        void printList();
};
```

I sorted it by `letterCount` on insertion already, but now I need to sort it by `timesUsed` within each individual letter count section and I am having trouble. I got it to traverse to the part of the list that needs to be sorted, but I have no clue how to actually sort this subsection

Here is the sorting code:

```cpp
void LinkedList:: sort(){
    Node *temp=head;
    bool wentin;
    while (temp->next!=NULL) {
        wentin=false;
        while (temp->letterCount==temp->next->letterCount) {
            //sort by times used here
            temp=temp->next;
            if (temp->next==NULL) {
                wentin=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (wentin==true) {
            break;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would traverse the list in block by each letter count amount and treat each amount like its own list that needs to be sorted (which you said you did correctly once already). Just be sure to save references to the correct head nodes as you go since it is a singly linked list. Breaking the logic into smaller functions may help simplify everything.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are making a separate sort function to sort by times used _or_ if you want your single sort function to first sort by letter count and then by times used if there is more than one node per letter count?

Comment: What if `head` is `NULL`?

Comment: Would be an option to sort on letterCount AND timeUsed at insertion ?